# Creating a boot drive for windows 10 on a non-empty drive

Tags: windows-10, laptop, external-hard-drive, system-repair-disc

All I have is an external hard drive two problematic computers, one of which won't fully boot, and fails to repair itself.

(just in case someone has experience with this problem, here's a quick version. Not much time to write everything properly since this computer won't charge. The actual question is after the following paragraph)

(due to critical process dying, the repair tool. It all started when I tried to wake it up from sleep, got a black screen but could hear the fan working full-power, forced shut down, tried to reboot, and got "the system detected a problem with the fan". from there it's just "gathering information on error, we'll restart for you", and then the repair tool attempting to run, and computer suddenly shuts down. Interrupting the boot and trying to fix it gives me a message that I'll need a recovery media or something like that)

Anyway, I don't want to wipe my external HD, but I have nothing else I can use as a recovery media.

All instructions say you need a clean USB drive. I'm hoping the external HD doesn't require installing any  drivers to use, and that there's a way to use it for recovery without wiping it... Is there?

Answer (score 1):

A way that might work according to the Microsoft article
[Create bootable WinPE media](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive),
is to partition the USB into two partitions.

Follow the article
[WinPE: Store or split images to deploy Windows using a single USB drive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe--use-a-single-usb-key-for-winpe-and-a-wim-file---wim#span-idcreateamultiplepartitionusbdrivespanoption-1-create-a-multiple-partition-usb-drive) to :

- Shrink your USB partition to have enough unused space for your files
- Format the new partition as NTFS
- Copy your files to it
- Install the recovery media to the first partition.

But I must caution that doing partition work is dangerous, since an error
can cost you the contents of the disk. If you don't have backup for the files,
I would really counsel getting another disk or flash key for the boot media.

Answer (score 0):

If your external hard disk has enough space to install the recovery media, you can try to partition your external hard disk and allocate some free space to install the recovery media. Just treat that new partition as you new "USB drive" and don't touch the other partition while creating your recovery media(don't choose the partition that you store your file).